# Passing websocket streaming data to child in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, jsx

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        chartData : {}
    };        

    let ws = new WebSocket('link');

    ws.onopen = function () {
        console.log('Successfully connected WebSocket!');
    };

    ws.onmessage = function (msg) {
        console.log("Message: " + msg.data);
        try {

            //Parse the message
            let obj = JSON.parse(msg.data);

        }catch(err){
            console.log('Error in onmessage: ' + err);
        }

    };
}
getChartData(){
    this.setState({chartData:[2,3,4,5,6] }) //Want to send obj from onmessage
}

componentWillMount(){
    this.getChartData();

};

render() {
    return (
     <div className="wrap"> 
       <Chart chartData={this.state.chartData} />
    )
}
```

This works fine if I have pasted the correct code! 
I get the data in Chart component such as:

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        chartData:props.chartData
    };
};
```

My question is, how do I send the obj from the ws.onmessage function because this function receives data every second.

Answer (score 1):

You're already keeping the chart data in `state` and passing it down as a `prop`. So, simply have your `onmessage` listener update your component `state` every time it gets new data.

```
ws.onmessage = (msg) => {
    console.log("Message: " + msg.data);
    try {

        //Parse the message
        let obj = JSON.parse(msg.data);
        this.setState({chartData: obj});

    }catch(err){
        console.log('Error in onmessage: ' + err);
    }
};
```

Note that the listener is now an arrow function so that it retains the proper `this` context.